# How to mount an SMB share as a removable media?

Tags: external-sd, mount, usb-mass-storage, cifs

Is it possible to mount an SMB share to a folder that Android thinks is a removable media (external SD card or USB storage)?

Currently. I am using the following command to mount the share to Android's filesystem (I should mention that it doesn't work if the android device is in battery saving mode - took me a while to figure this out):

```
busybox mount iocharset=utf8 -t cifs -o username=guest,rw,noperm,iocharset=utf8 //192.168.0.11/xxx /data/media/0/xxx
```

But, I don't think it's the best way, because I had some media scanner crashes, random reboots and notifications about low internal memory, which I think are related to the mount I performed.

Comment: Hi, I think the crashes and reboots happened because of additional media scanner apps, that I have installed one after the other. Because restoring a backup and not using these apps helped (I hope). But I edited the question again to bring back the information :)

Comment: Thanks for adding it back. It helps us to know what you've tried, so that we can help you out with the same or find issues and provide an alternative, wherever needed. :-)